# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable(python)

Tags: python

I have following class in python:

```
class State:
    def __init__(self,current):
       self.state=list(current)
       self.costToPath=0
       self.stepToPath=[]

    def costToPath(self,parent):
        self.costToPath=parent.getCostToPath()+1

    def stepToPath(self,path):
       self.stepToPath.append(path)

    def setState(self,newState):
        self.state=list(newState)

    def getState(self):
       return self.state

    def getPath(self):
        return self.stepToPath

    def getCostToPath(self):
        return self.costToPath
```

and when I try to make object os State and call the function costToStep like:

```
s=State([1,2,3])
s.stepToPath("up")
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: traceback please.

Comment: i think the problem is with the name of the list , which is the same as the function name ,  so python is calling the list as the function. try changing the name of the list

Comment: Thanks @Alireza, solution found